# How to do one user postgresql with privileges only execute functions

Tags: postgresql, function, privileges, sql-grant, role

I want create users that only can execute functions from one database. Not view source functions, procedures, select, etc of any database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

- Allow the user to connect to only the correct database, either with permissions on the database object (you have to `REVOKE` the `CONNECT` privilege granted to `PUBLIC` by default first) or with suitable entries in `pg_hba.conf`.
- In the one database where the user can connect, it should have `USAGE` privilege on the schemas that contain the functions.
- Create functions with `SECURITY INVOKER` that belong to a user that has the rights to access the required objects.
- `REVOKE EXECUTE` on all functions from `PUBLIC` and `GRANT` it to the user as required.

There is no supported way in PostgreSQL to keep a user that can log on from seeing the source code of functions. You can try to `REVOKE SELECT ON pg_proc FROM PUBLIC`, but don't be surprised if you get problems with client programs like pgAdmin or `psql`.

Comment: Thanks @laurenz-albe, I'll try it!